# Exclude a line within a hunk in git commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there a way in IntelliJ to exclude certain lines within a code chunk from git commit?

Say for example I have the following change:-

[image]

I want to exclude the last line (*ADMIN_API_URL*) from being committed.

I know I can do partial commits by clicking on that small checkbox next to the line number 49 ([as described here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/)), but that would remove the whole hunk. I just want to remove specific lines. If there is no straight way to do this, is there a way to split a hunk into multiple hunks? Then I would be able to do what I want.

I can do this in Sourcetree by right clicking on some lines and selecting "Stage Selected Lines". Just want to know how to do it in IntelliJ and also, it would be good to know how to do this using git commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want if you use the git command line with `git add -p` command :
Edit the hunk by typing 'e' when you are prompted :

```bash
$ git add -p
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? e
```

The default text editor opens, replace the line `+ADMIN_API_URL` by `+` (remove the text `ADMIN_API_URL`).

Save and exit the editor and **you are done**.

You can execute

- `git diff --staged` to see that your next commit will not contain the last line,
- and `git diff` to see that the last line still exists in your working copy.

Comment: This doesn't answer my primary question about IntelliJ. I guess (as mentioned by @VonC) IntelliJ doesn't support it. Thanks for the git explanation though.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible now, but it's a bit complicated, and it requires selecting `Enable staging area` in Git preferences.  (Selecting that disables Changelists, the other mode that IntelliJ supports. You can only use one or the other mode at a time.)

Search for "To stage granular changes like a single line instead of a code chunk, or even one of a number of changes to a single line" in this document: [Commit and push changes to Git repository | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#git-stage-changes)

You have to use a special 3-way side-by-side diff view that you get by right-clicking the file and selecting `Compare HEAD, Staged and Local versions`.  You can also access that command as an action (Cmd-Shift-A) or give it a shortcut, and it will work on the currently-edited file.

Answer (score 0):

> it would be good to know how to do this using git commands.

When doing a `git add -p`, you have the option to edit an hunk: you can then delete the last line.

I don't think that InelliJ, when [applying a patch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-patch-dialog.html), would offer a similar option. See [issue IDEA-63201](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201#focus=streamItem-27-1812462-0-0).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do what you ask for except by [using git fron the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662377/16038645) or [using the 3-way-diff-view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73723945/16038645).

Tho luckly there is a proper solution in the works!

There is currently an Issue on JetBrains's YouTrack regarding this: [Issue: Allow commiting only specific lines](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988) and it's currently marked as `In progress`.

It's also the most upvoted `In progress` Issue as of now:
[JetBrain's YouTrack Issues sorted by most upvoted and only showing "In progress" ones](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=sort%20by:%20votes%20desc%20State:%20Acknowledged%20State:%20%7BIn%20progress%7D).

Hopefully it will get implemented soon as it's been asked since 2018 and lots of people still ask for it quite frequently even [today](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186988/Allow-commiting-only-specific-lines#focus=Comments-27-7888124.0-0).